# Can we tell SCSS to not generate unneeded class combinations in a comma seperated class list?

Tags: sass

Let's say I have:

```
.foo-1, .foo-2 {
  \\ styling ABC

  .bar-1, .bar-2 {
    \\ styling XYZ
  }
}
```

Is there a way to link classes to avoid creating unneeded classes? Or a command to tell SCSS "exclude these combinations". For example I only need:

```
.foo-1, 
.foo-2 {
  \\ styling ABC
}

.foo-1 .bar-1,
.foo-2 .bar-2 {
  \\ styling XYZ
}

\\ Dont want these
.foo-1 .bar-2,
.foo-2 .bar-1 {
  \\ styling XYZ
}
```

The goal is to have minimum code. I know I can use extend, mixins or whatever. But all these lead to more code than to live with bloated class lists.

For example I don't want it to write like:

```
.foo-1, .foo-2 {
  \\ styling ABC
}

.foo-1 .bar-1, .foo-2 .bar-2 {
  \\ styling XYZ
}
```

A more complex example:

```
.foo-list-item-details,
.foo-detail-item-details {
    @include grid-gap(10px);
    display : grid;

    .foo-list-item-detail,
    .foo-detail-item-detail {
        @include gap(5px);
        display     : flex;
        align-items : center;
    }

    .foo-list-item-detail {
        .foo-detail-value {
            @include font-size(13px);
        }
    }

    .foo-detail-item-detail {
        .foo-detail-label {
            @include width(30px);
            @include min-width(30px);
            font-weight : $font-weight-bold;

            i,
            svg {
                @include font-size(18px);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles to a lot of unwanted code. I hoped there would be some chance to tell the compiler "pair the list and detail thingies together".

I want:

```
.foo-list-item-details {}
.foo-list-item-details .foo-list-item-detail {}

.foo-detail-item-details .foo-detail-item-detail {}

// list to list, detail to detail
```

Comment: This is pretty antithetical to the meaning of nesting in CSS. In this case, perhaps you could do a `@each $i from 1 through 2`, then print `.foo-#{$i}{ /*ABC*/ .bar-#{$i}{ /*XYZ*/ } }`?

Comment: @somethinghere thank you but this only works for iterable class names. mines are not.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide more details on what do you want to archive, the answer could be more specific. In general: Trying to avoid mention of the parent selectors will result in less code and faster browser rendering.

```css
.foo-1,
.foo-2 { 
  ...
}

.bar-1 {
  ...
}

.bar-2 {
  ...
}
```

Another way is to make the use of a modular `.bar`, if it is mostly similar in both parents elements (`.foo-1` and `.foo-2`) but this little differences.

```
.bar {
  border: 2px solid red;

  // .bar is within .foo-1
  .foo-1 & {
    background: red;
  }

  // .bar is within .foo-1
  .foo-2 & {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: added a more complex example. Your first example is exactly what I do not want to do. I know I can "denest" the whole thing, work with extend, placeholders and whatever but this results in a lot more code someone must maintain. Your last example does not work either in my case. Every .bar would get a border even if I only want them in foo-1 and foo-2.